# python based program exe taking more time to load

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I am working on python + pygtk based UI application on Windows.

I am generating .exe file from my python source code using pyinstaller pkg.

After getting .exe file, file size comes to around 36 MB.

This file is taking around 42 sec to open UI on Windows 8.1 with corei3 processor and 26 sec to open same on Windows 10 with core i7 processor.

I am not getting why its taking so much time?

Idea is to build windows based package, with no dependencies.

.exe file should have all the required pkgs including python.

Can any one give me better way of doing it?

Comment: The .exe file contains all Python modules it needs in zipped form. They need to be unpacked on startup, which takes time.

Comment: This is why programs are usually installed, so that they don't need to reload all the resources and unpack them everytime

Comment: There are of course ways of building the exe file and the python modules separately, but that is a subject of another question, and you'll have to show some of your own research and code...

Comment: See [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1782). Basically it's working as intended.

Comment: Are you using --onefile flag to have just one file in the folder where you have your executable? If you don't need to have it as just one file, you could have all your dependencies in that same folder instead of creating it in a temp file every time you open the application. This could improve speeds significantly but it really depends on your use case